# Некорректный вывод русских символов в консоль при работе с Logger'ом

Tags: java, кодировка, логирование, encoder

Прохожу обучение java и с столкнулся с проблемой вывода текста на русском языке в консоль при работе с Logger. Хотя при sysout все выводиться отлично... Поигрался с кодировками в VSC, ничего не помогло.
Вот пример лога:

> фхъ. 24, 2023 4:04:33 PM java_lessons.lesson_2.ex_4.Main4 writeToFile
> INFO: ╟ряшё№ т Їрщы яЁю°ыр єёях°эю

**Кодировка** (и она же по умолчанию): UTF-8

**Charset.defaultCharset()**: windows-1251 (Не знаю что это, но если поможет решению-прописал в том же java  файле)

Вызываемый метод:

```
static void writeToFile(String filePath, String res) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filePath)) {
        fw.write(res);
        logger.info("Запись в файл прошла успешно");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.warning("Запись в файл не удалась");
    }
}
```

Обычный вывод и ввод русских символов в консоль работают отлично, проблема именно с классом Logger

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0&searchOn=3)

Comment: Я так понял нужно куда-то вставить encoding "utf8", но куда бы я его не вставил, везде вылазит ошибка. А (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0&searchOn=3) нахожу ответы только с чтением файлов или просто вывод в консоль. Но обычный вывод у меня работает, а файл я не читаю

Comment: Вроде все починил добавив кодировку в handler и FileWriter (что логично), проблема была в том что нужно указать именно сам charset, а не имя charset'а с помощью StandartCharset.UTF-8. 
Главное чтение работает нормально, без явного указания кодировки.... НО
Появилась новая проблема, в терминале не отображается кириллица которую я указал в коде или запросил ввести пользователя, хотя с файла отлично все выводит как и записывает

Comment: Короче, есть в параметрах винды (11) настройка: Бета-версия: использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире. Так вот если ставить галочку, то чтение и запись в файл работают лучше, но ввод и вывод в консоли вообще не работают. А если убрать, то нужно явно указывать кодировку при работе с файлами и логами, зато вывод в консоль начинает правильно работать, НО перестает работать ввод XD


Путь к этой настройке: параметры -> время и язык -> язык и регион -> административные языковые параметры -> изменить язык системы

Я устал, пойду отдыхать)